# subprocess.Popen and the maximum character length of its arguments

Tags: python, subprocess

I had a fairly simple line in my python code:

```
Popen(["t2x",cfile],env=denv,stdout=h)
```

This line has a bug, and I ended up realizing that the name of the input file `cfile` is too long. Thus, I'm getting a segmentation fault. I know this must be the problem, because I can run the same code with a shorter `cfile` path and it works.

The question is how long can the name `cfile` be? If I also have `cwd=dir`, do I also have a limit on the number of characters for `dir`? Can we get around these limits?

Below is the offending code and the error message:

```
import os
import subprocess

dir="/scratch" 

cfile="/home/user/simulation_data/2017_systemBC_efield/BCline01/bssecorrection/bsseE=0+H2(1)/scan_0000/bsse/coord"

xyz="temp.xyz"

denv=dict(os.environ)

with open(xyz,"w") as h:
    p1=subprocess.Popen(["t2x",coordfile],env=denv,cwd=dir,stdout=h)
    p1.wait()
```

**Error message:**

```
Taking coordinates from file:  /home/user/simulation_data/2017_systemBC_efield/BCline01/bssecorrection/bsseE=0+H2(1)/scan_0000/bsse/coord
No structure optimization data found.
Only coord data will be converted.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: well it depends. In your case not upon Popen. not at least with python 2.7

You could test to change the command from "t2x" to "ls" instead and you will see that it will execute without a problem.

That leads us to the conclusion that t2x is allocating a buffer that is to small for the given arguments and maybe also permitting a bufferflow, a guess made from the fact that you are getting seg-faults

Comment: @DavidBern I feel a little silly. Indeed, the t2x script was the problem. Unfortunately, I can't fix it.

Comment: Do you have access to the source-code?

Comment: @DavidBern I do, but I won't modify it right now, because it would take me a little. I'll get to it at some point, or ask the developers to fix it in the next release.

Comment: It sounds and looks like a simple problem to fix.